# Implementing RSA-SHA1 signature algorithm in Java (creating a private key for use with OAuth RSA-SHA1 signature)

Tags: java, oauth, digital-signature

As you know, OAuth can support RSA-SHA1 Signature. I have an `OAuthSignature` interface that has the following method

```
public String sign(String data, String consumerSecret, String tokenSecret) throws GeneralSecurityException;
```

I successfully implemented and tested HMAC-SHA1 Signature (which OAuth Supports) as well as the PLAINTEXT "signature".

I have searched google and I have to create a private key if I need to use `SHA1withRSA` signature: Sample code:

```
  /**
   * Signs the data with the given key and the provided algorithm.
   */
  private static byte[] sign(PrivateKey key,
                             String data)
      throws GeneralSecurityException {

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    signature.initSign(key);
    signature.update(data.getBytes());
    return signature.sign();
  }
```

Now, How can I take the OAuth key (which is key = consumerSecret&tokenSecret) and create a `PrivateKey` to use with `SHA1withRSA` signature?

Thanks

---

From [**OAuth Core**](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor19)

> 9.3.  RSA-SHA1
>
> The RSA-SHA1 signature method uses the
>   RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature algorithm
>   as defined in [RFC3447] (Jonsson, J.
>   and B. Kaliski, “Public-Key
>   Cryptography Standards (PKCS) #1: RSA
>   Cryptography; Specifications Version
>   2.1,” .) section 8.2 (more simply known as PKCS#1), using SHA-1 as the
>   hash function for EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5. It
>   is assumed that the Consumer has
>   provided its RSA public key in a
>   verified way to the Service Provider,
>   in a manner which is beyond the scope
>   of this specification.

And I'm now using this (http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html) as a reference to doing RSA-SHA1 signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What API is the `OAuthSignature` interface from?  Is it possible that the `tokenSecret` parameter is not necessary for RSA signatures?

Comment: `OAuthSignature` is my own interface. And you are correct, Using Google example (http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html) It seems that it doesn't require Token Secret.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the RSA-SHA1 does't need the consumer secret, you can refer the Jersey implement here https://svn.java.net/svn/jersey~svn/trunk/jersey/contribs/jersey-oauth/oauth-signature/src/main/java/, the class com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.RSA_SHA1.